# config error : Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.paths.url

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, web3js, hardhat

this is my hardhat.config.js file code :

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks : {
    hardhat :{
      chainId: 1337,
    },
  
  paths :{
    artifacts: "./src/artifacts",
  },
},
};
```

and when i compile this using `npx hardhat compile`

it shows following error :

> Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

> - Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.paths.url - Expected a value of type
>   string.

> To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config

for your reference i am following this tutorial for building this web3 project : "https://blog.suhailkakar.com/setup-and-build-your-first-web-3-application"

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the network's bracket after the hardhat chain Id :)

Please replace your module.exports object with this

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks:{
    hardhat:{
      chainId: 1337,
    }
  },
  paths:{
    artifacts: "./src/artifacts"
  }
};
```

P.S: Thanks for pointing this out, I have also updated my article

Answer (score 0):

Required dotenv before using process.env values in hardhat.config.js

```bash
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
const RINKEBY_RPC_URL = process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const PRIVATE_KEY_USER1 = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_USER1
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            { version: "0.8.8" },
            { version: "0.6.6" },
            { version: "0.8.16" },
        ],
    },
    networks: {
        rinkeby: {
            url: RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY_USER1],
            chainId: 4,
        },
    },
}
```